# combine two byte[] in SHA512Digest 's doFinal

Tags: byte, codenameone, bouncycastle, sha512

in this methode there is only one instruction that not working:

```
private static byte[] encodePassword(String password,String salt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
         {      

    String mergedPasswordAndSalt =mergePasswordAndSalt(password, salt);
    SHA512Digest digester =new  SHA512Digest();   

    byte[] hash = new byte[digester.getDigestSize()];   
    digester.update(hash, 0, mergedPasswordAndSalt.length());
    digester.doFinal(hash, 0);
             System.out.println("init hash= "+Base64.encode(hash));          
    for (int  i = 1; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
         digester.update(hash, 0, mergedPasswordAndSalt.length());  

        digester.doFinal(Bytes.concat(hash, mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")),0); 

    }     
    System.out.println("FINAL hash= "+Base64.encode(hash));
    return hash;
}
```

that instructions: is the equivalent of this one in the java api that is way:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        hash = digester.digest(Bytes.concat(hash, mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the iterations loop and why you invoke doFinal more than once?

Comment: Thanks for response ,because i am using a ready database that was created by FOSUser Bundle, and this database has that way of encryption look at this 
 link please 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution:
To concat bytes i used this method:

```
public static byte[] concat(byte[]... arrays) {
    int length = 0;
    byte[][] arr$ = arrays;
    int pos = arrays.length;

    for(int i$ = 0; i$ < pos; ++i$) {
        byte[] array = arr$[i$];
        length += array.length;
    }

    byte[] result = new byte[length];
    pos = 0;
    byte[][] arr$$=arrays; 
    arr$=arr$$;
    int len$ = arrays.length;

    for(int i$ = 0; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
        byte[] array = arr$[i$];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, pos, array.length);
        pos += array.length;
    }

    return result;
}
```

To do 4999 iteration on the digest we need a method that takes the hash after every iteration and works in the current digest concatenated with the first diegest(generate out of loop):

```
private static byte[] encodePassword(String password,String salt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
             {                       
        String mergedPasswordAndSalt =mergePasswordAndSalt(password, salt);


    byte[] hash = new byte[88];   

   hash=digestt(mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8"));                                
    for (int  i = 1; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {                                                          
        hash=digestt(concat(hash,mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    }     

    return hash;
}

public static byte[] digestt(byte[] bytes) {
    Digest digest = new SHA512Digest();
    byte[] resBuf = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];

    digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    digest.doFinal(resBuf, 0);
    return resBuf;
}
```

thank you very much i asked many questions and you are always there for help.